# Which pipe thread compound/dope options can be combined with PTFE tape?

Tags: plumbing

As I am shopping for pipe thread compound/dope I find there are some major categories that seem to have different use cases but I am not sure about all the pros and cons. Most discussions online lump all these products together as "pipe dope", but I am worried about the distinctions.

In particular, I have in front of me one compound that contains TFE, and one that contains oils and lithium and minerals which is labeled to avoid use on plastic pipes.

Will the TFE compound react negatively with PTFE tape? Will the no-plastics-allowed oil compound?

Comment: PTFE or Teflon is chemically inert to just about anything I would not have a problem using both.

Comment: @EdBeal if I had to guess at the exception to that "just about anything", my top guess would be whatever keeps the teflon compound liquid.

Comment: Teflon is a solid the other materials in dope will not damage it being water based or anything used as a dope on any kind of pipe ie if it is compatible with the pipe material it will not damage the pipe , I have doing this for residential and commercial work for over 30 years including chemical wet processing in clean rooms where the risk was contamination of the chemicals in the 5 nines range just so you understand 99.999 % pure with many different chemicals we used combinations of dope and tape to prevent gaulling of stainless.

Comment: @EdBeal Are you using teflon dope or oil+mineral+grease dope or something else?

Answer (score 1):

The Teflon in pipe dope paste advertised as containing Teflon is not in solution, but in the form of fine particles. There is nothing in any pipe dope which could dissolve Teflon